# Set background of remotedesktop while displaying user environment program

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019

I have set up a Windows Server 2019 as a remote desktop host, using user CALs.
When a user logs on to the server, he is locked in a program specified in his user settings. This all works fine, but now some of our customers complained about the black background behind the application.

Is there any possibility to set the background to another color?

Comment: `Is there any possibility to set the background to another color?` - Yes, there is.

Comment: @joeqwerty would you mind to elaborate on your comment? How? Because no desktop is shown, none of the settings I tried had any effect.